# codeigniter confirmation box before delete

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to show a box before someone click "eliminar"
thats my view:

```
echo '<td><a href="' . base_url() . 'index.php/utilizadores/delete/' . $value->id_user . '" ><p class="eliminar">Eliminar</p></a></td></tr>';
```

thats my controller:

```
public function delete()
    {
        $uri = &load_class('URI', 'core');
        $id = $uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->load->model('utilizadoresModel');

        $this->utilizadoresModel->delete($id);

        redirect('utilizadores');
    }
```

And thats my model:

```
function delete($id){
    $this->db->delete('utilizadores', array('id_user' => $id));
  }
```

And thanks for the help :D

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a confirmation dialog, you could use javascript onclick event listener :

```js
echo '<td><a href="' . base_url() . 'index.php/utilizadores/delete/' . $value->id_user . '" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item\')" ><p class="eliminar">Eliminar</p></a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: Erro:
An Error Was Encountered
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

Comment: glad I could help ;)

Comment: @TiagoNunes On Stack Exchange sites the way to say *thank you* is to 
[upvote helpful answers and accept the most helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the tick mark on the left. You're free to switch later when a better answer comes along.